# Bass needs a cleanin'

Tags: guitar, bass-guitar

So I bought a used bass and I can tell the previous owner has stickers on it because the pick guard is an eggshell color and the shape of the stickers is still white. Any idea on how to clean this?[image]

Comment: It's possible that it's not dirt or grime. It could be due to exposure to sunlight which accelerates the curing of the plastic. Either way, there might be nothing you can do besides replace the pick guard. Or put your own stickers on to cover up the discoloration.

Answer (score 7):

As Todd Wilcox says in his comment, it looks like yellowing that has taken place due to light exposure. If so, it's not going to be something you can clean in the conventional sense.

Over time, you'll probably find that the white patches themselves start to yellow and the contrast will decrease, although this may take years.

This looks like a conventional bass design (?) so you may find that an off-the-shelf pick-guard replacement that fits can be bought cheaply; even if not, it's not super-expensive to have one made.

Comment: Looks like a Jazz bass. The single-ply white pickguard suggests older Squier or Mexican Fender, which should make tracking down an aftermarket pickguard a little easier.

Comment: For that matter, this could be an opportunity to switch to a black or other fancy color http://www.guitarcenter.com/search?Ns=r&Ntt=Fender+Pickguards+Bass&source=4WWRWXGB&gclid=CMnO9O3l39ECFYOGaQodvEUGmA&kwid=679226403x7516251373x134650693

Answer (score 1):

You could try  [T-Cut](http://www.halfords.com/motoring/paints-body-repair/scratch-repair-paint-restorers/t-cut-scratch-remover-150g) which is used to shine up tired paintwork on cars.

It's not a polish - it works as an abrasive / fine rubbing compound. Put a bit on a cloth, and as you rub, it takes off a very thin layer off the top (not perceptible - paint is very thin!). It works on plasticy type stuff too, which paint is really,  so it might get the plastic back to its original colour.

However. .. It's likely that the "Real" colour is what was under the stickers, and the darker colour around it is what needs cleaning.

Be sure to try it on a small spot first

Comment: alternative answer : find some sticker sthat match the discolouration ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can buy cleaning liquid spray for UPVC windows which completely solves that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the pick guard is ABS plastic, the yellowing can be reversed using what is called [retrobright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retr0bright), which is a homemade solution largely consisting of hydrogen peroxide and a little "Oxy" cleaner. For complex shapes, people add gelatin and/or xanthan gum to make it adhere better to surfaces.

One would then use the sun or a UV lamp to expose the object to UV, which reverses the reaction that causes the yellowing.

Comment: Note that UV lamps can be dangerous to one's vision, and the chemicals can harm one's eyes and skin if not handled properly.